# Есть ли возможность в js при объявлении класса указать для this на другой экземпляр созданного объекта?

Tags: javascript, node.js

У меня есть класс:

```
let object = class SameClass{
 constructor(){


 }
}
```

Я создаю 2 объекта этого класса.

```
let first = new object()
let second = new object()
```

И вопрос у меня вот в чём.
Есть ли возможность при создании второго класса, указать в конструкторе для второго класса ссылку на первый. Фактически что бы второй класс ссылался на первый и был с ним одним и тем же объектом.

То есть

Дописать класс

```
let object = class SameClass{
static #class = undefined
 constructor(){

  if(this.#class === undefined){
   this.#class.first = this
  }else{
    ???---Вопрос как здесь можно переопределить this---???
  }
 }
}
```

Дополнение:

```
<custom-element-1>
  <script>
  import object from '/path/to/you/component'

   object = "~~~~~~~~ Как мне получать экземпляр класса ? ~~~~~~~~~~"
   object = getInstance()

  </script>
</custom-element-1>
<custom-element-2>
  <script>
  import object from '/path/to/you/component'

   object = "~~~~~~~~ Как мне получать экземпляр класса ? ~~~~~~~~~~"
   object = getInstance()

  </script>
</custom-element-2>
<custom-element-3>
   <script>
  import object from '/path/to/you/component'

   object = "~~~~~~~~ Как мне получать экземпляр класса ? ~~~~~~~~~~"
   object = getInstance()

  </script>
</custom-element-3>
<custom-element-4>
  <script>
  import object from '/path/to/you/component'

   object = "~~~~~~~~ Как мне получать экземпляр класса ? ~~~~~~~~~~"
   object = getInstance()

  </script>
</custom-element-4>
```

Я не знаю время когда загружается какой то из компонентов и в каком порядке.

[image: Я не знаю время когда загружается какой то из компонентов и в каком порядке.]

Comment: а зачем создавать два объекта если нужен один?

Comment: Способ объявления одинаковый.  Послезавтра я забуду свою писанину и забуду объявлял я класс и если объявлял, где мне его найти и т д... но не забуду как объявляется класс.

Comment: не понял как объявление связано с вопросом

Comment: В дополнении привёл пример. У меня n-e колличество компоненов мне нужен простой способ получения объекта этого класса. Универсальный. Я его буду использовать во всех объектах сейчас. Код максимально простой должен быть.

Comment: эм, если код как в дополнении, то достаточно возвращать объект из `import object from '/path/to/you/component'` и тогда следующих строк, где ты этой же (?) переменной что-то присваиваешь - не нужно

Comment: let node = object['staticProperty']['node']

node ....

Я могу так вызывать...Но вы видимо большой объем кода не писали. Я повторю мне максимально простой способ нужен, о котором мне даже думать не придётся ( идеальный вариант это что то из коробки, вариант который ниже привели наверное самый оптимальный ( у меня так же но более громоздко был собранно)

Comment: Не факт даже что он существовать будет в это время с таким вызовом.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103051/discussion-between-grundy-and-sergey).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function getInstance() {

  class Test {
  }
  
  if (!getInstance.instance) {
    getInstance.instance = new Test();
  }
  return getInstance.instance;
}

let a = getInstance();
let b = getInstance();
console.log(a == b);
```